# How to search ST_MakePoint(long,lat) in all the geometry columns of tables in the database(postgres)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry

I want to search a particular given given lat,long within all the <strike>shapefiles</strike> geometry columns of all tables in the database .

I have gone through the scripts like below

```
CREATE TABLE #Results (geom)

SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
    SET  @TableName = ''
    SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                        OBJECT_ID(
                            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                             ), 'IsMSShipped'
                               ) = 0
        )

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName =
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                    AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                    AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                    AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
            )

            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                )
            END
        END 
    END

    SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
END
```

2. other model

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_columns1(IN needle text, IN haystack_tables name[] DEFAULT '{}'::name[], IN haystack_schema name[] DEFAULT '{public,road_layers,s10k,s50d,s50k,sds}'::name[])
      RETURNS TABLE(schemaname text, tablename text, columnname text, rowctid text) AS
    $BODY$
    begin
      FOR schemaname,tablename,columnname IN
          SELECT c.table_schema,c.table_name,c.column_name
          FROM information_schema.columns c
          JOIN information_schema.tables t ON
            (t.table_name=c.table_name AND t.table_schema=c.table_schema)
          WHERE (c.table_name=ANY(haystack_tables) OR haystack_tables='{}')
            AND c.table_schema=ANY(haystack_schema)
            AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE'
      LOOP
        EXECUTE format('SELECT ctid FROM %I.%I WHERE cast(%I as text) ILIKE %L',
           schemaname,
           tablename,
           columnname,
           needle
        ) INTO rowctid;
        IF rowctid is not null THEN
          RETURN NEXT;
        END IF;
     END LOOP;
    END;
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100
      ROWS 1000;
    ALTER FUNCTION search_columns1(text, name[], name[])
      OWNER TO postgres;
```

3.Third option

```
DO $$
    DECLARE
      value int := 0;
      sql text := 'The constructed select statement';
      rec1 record;
      rec2 record;
    BEGIN
      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _x;
      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _x (
        schema_name text, 
        table_name text, 
        column_name text,
        found text
      );
      FOR rec1 IN 
            SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name
            FROM information_schema.columns 
            WHERE table_name <> '_x'
                    AND UPPER(column_name) LIKE UPPER('%%')                  
                    AND table_schema <> 'pg_catalog'
                    AND table_schema <> 'information_schema'
                    AND data_type IN ('character varying', 'text', 'character', 'char', 'varchar')
            LOOP
        sql := concat('SELECT ', rec1."column_name", ' AS "found" FROM ',rec1."table_schema" , '.',rec1."table_name" , ' WHERE UPPER(',rec1."column_name" , ') LIKE UPPER(''','%%' , ''')');
        RAISE NOTICE '%', sql;
        BEGIN
            FOR rec2 IN EXECUTE sql LOOP
                RAISE NOTICE '%', sql;
                INSERT INTO _x VALUES (rec1."table_schema", rec1."table_name", rec1."column_name", rec2."found");
            END LOOP;
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        END;
      END LOOP;
      END; $$;

    SELECT * FROM _x;
```

Comment: "Shapefile" isn't a generic term for "spatial data" -- It's a specific file-based format which has nothing to do with database tables. You should not use `ST_MakePoint` with "lat,long" parameters, since the  correct order is {X,Y}, which woild be {lon,lat}. Your question does not contain a question. Please **edit** it to specify ***one*** code block and the the errors generated by that code.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. I think you want to find all possible geometry columns and then search for a specific value in those columns?

Comment: yes sir exactly.

Comment: can you expalin with example sir or any refrence links also helpful

Answer (score -1):

[ST_Contains](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) will tell you if a point is contained within a geometry.

Here is a simple example of how to use it to compare a specific point against a table named 'polygons' with a geometry column named 'geom' with an SRID of 4326:

```
SELECT ST_Contains(geom,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-71.0, 42.3),4326))
FROM polygons
```